# Ext js and sencha cmd compatibility matrix

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have ext js **6.5** and sencha cmd **6.2**. while trying to create an app with ext js sdk it fails. I would like to know which cmd version is compatible with ext js 6.5 sdk.

Answer (score 0):

There is an outdated [Cmd Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.7.0/guides/compatibility_matrix.html#compatibility_matrix_-_ext_js) in Sencha Cmd Guides. But, as you can observe from it, the minimum cmd version for *Ext JS 5.1.0* is *5.1.0*, which means that the previous *5.0.1* Cmd version is not working. There were quite some changes introduced in ExtJS 6.5 and it's not a surprise to me that it doesn't work with Cmd 6.2. You can easily upgrade Cmd by running: `sencha upgrade`.

If you have other projects that rely on older versions of Cmd (theoretically the latest version would be able to handle them), you can switch easily between versions.

First use the `sencha which` command that will display the active Cmd version.
Then you can use `sencha switch --list` command that will display all the version installed on your machine. After that you can easily switch to the required version by running `sencha switch %version_number%`.